# Can we use prepositional "Of" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

1. I take my coffee with milk and sugar.

=) With milk and sugar, I take my coffee.

But

2. Today is the first day of the month.

=) Of the month, today is the first day.

3. He is the son of Bill.

=) Of Bill, he is the son.

I know Nb1 is correct, but inside Nb2 and Nb3 three there may be problem starting with preposition OF. what do you think?Can we use preposition "Of" as all other prepositions.

Comment: Have you ever heard anyone talking like that? Please don't try to emulate Yoda.

Comment: None of your examples are idiomatic, and I don't understand exactly what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not in the manner that you have done.

> Of all the places we visited on our trip, __________ was by far the
>   most beautiful.

There must be some "rhetorical" reason to begin the sentence with a prepositional phrase where the preposition is **of**.

> Of the options presented to us, it was the least expensive.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* but *don't*, unless you have a very good reason.

It is hard to think of a context in which these sentences would be a good choice. Even the first (that you know is correct) is doubtful. The others are just not used, unless (as noted in a comment) you are Yoda from Star wars.

Perhaps when you want a marked contrast by bringing the Of phrase to the front it may be possible.

> Of these matters I will not speak.